# (Java/C#) GUI Configuration Editor with XML Output

Tags: c#, java, xml, frameworks, editor

I'm using XML configuration files with custom XML tags in a small javascript opensource project.
The framework takes xml config files written by the user.
Because simple XML is a little bit too much for some users and it feels like handcoding, I want to build a little editor. 
The XML Files are really small and simple: An Text (maybe with html formatting), and two other text parameters (simple tags) (one has an additional binary option)

I thought this use case happens regularly and perhaps someone has coded a framework or template for building such an editor. I could really save some time.
I googled for that, but found nothing.

The language, which the template/framework uses isn't important, but I would prefer Java, C# or Python to run it on many platforms.

Does anybody know a tool, framework, template I could use?

Comment: You may find some products for this, but it's often better to build your own small utility using Java or .NET Forms or .NET WPF to accomplish your goal. This way it will be customized to meet your particular situation.

Comment: Right, customized solutions could be better, but I have to care about everything - loading and parsing of xml, show error messages, writing xml files and so on. I thought there might be a template available for that to skip these parts. (I already know good xml libraries)